# How to get data from sqlite and response json using scotty?

Tags: json, haskell, functional-programming, scotty

I'm trying to build a simple blog using Haskell and the Framework Scotty. Using a Model.hs I have:

```
data Post = Post
    { id :: Int
    , tipo :: String
    , titulo :: String
    , conteudo :: String
    } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

I've already create a schema using sqlite and populate with some data, right now I'm trying to get this data using this method in my Storage.hs

```
selectPosts :: Sql.Connection -> IO [M.Post]
selectPosts conn =
    Sql.query_ conn "select * from post" :: IO [M.Post]
```

My intent is get the data format as json in my Main.hs:

```
instance ToJSON M.Post
instance FromJSON M.Post

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Starting Server..."
    scotty 3000 $ do
        get "/" $ file "templates/index.html"
        get "/posts" $ do
            json posts where
            posts = withTestConnection $ \conn -> do
                S.selectPosts conn
```

But I'm getting an IO [Model Post] and I don't know how to render this as json, so its keeping getting this error:

```
No instance for (ToJSON (IO [Post])) arising from a use of ‘json’
```

My project is in [github](https://github.com/itepifanio/programacao-funcional/tree/master/fun-blog) to run just use stack build and after stack ghci. In the building I'm already getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell, all functions are pure---so something like `selectPosts`, which needs to go out and do IO to talk to a database, can't just do that and return the value from the database. Instead, these kinds of functions return something of type `IO a`, which you can think of as basically a description of how to go out and do IO to get a value of type `a`.  These "IO actions" can be composed together, and one of them can be assigned to `main`; at runtime, the RTS will execute these IO actions.

However, you aren't composing the `IO a` value that you get back from `selectPosts` to be part of the larger `IO` value that eventually becomes `main`; you are trying to directly use it by feeding it into `json`.  This won't work, because there's no (good/easy) way to convert a description of how to do IO into a JSON string.

The way that Haskell deals with composing these values is through an abstraction known as a "monad", which is useful in a lot of other cases as well. `do` notation can be used to write this monadic sequencing in a very natural style. You can't just write `posts <- withTestConnection S.selectPosts` here because Scotty's `get` function takes a value of the monadic `ActionM` type, not `IO`. However, it turns out that `ActionM` is basically a bunch of other useful stuff layered on top of `IO`, so it should be possible to "lift" the IO action from `selectPosts` into Scotty's `ActionM` monad:

```
get "/posts" $ do
  posts <- liftIO $ withTestConnection S.selectPosts
  json posts
```

Side note: You may have noticed that I wrote `withTestConnection S.selectPosts` instead of `withTestConnection $ \conn -> do S.selectPosts conn`.  Generally, if you have a `do` block with only one expression in it (not of the form `x <- act`), this is the same as the single expression outside of a `do` block: `\conn -> S.selectPosts conn`.  Furthermore, Haskell tends to encourage partial application: you have `S.selectPosts`, which is a function `Sql.Connection -> IO [M.Post]`. `\conn -> S.selectPosts conn` is another function, of the same type, which passes the connection into `selectPosts` and then returns the same result as `selectPosts`---this function is indistinguishable from `selectPosts` itself! So if this is all that you need inside your `withTestConnection`, you should be able to simplify the whole lambda and `do` block to just `S.selectPosts`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the didactic explanation. I'm still learning haskell, but I had to begin this project with just the knowledge from list, recursion and others basic things. Just right now I'm really learning how the Monads works.
Furthermore, thanks for the tip too.